# Pasar un variable en lugar de un valor como argumento en python

Tags: python, lista, variables, parametros, indices

```
lista=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ultimo=lista.pop()
print(lista.index(ultimo))#¿Cómo pasar aquí el 9 obtenido en la variable ultimo
```

Hola, necesito obtener el índice de un valor (9) que está dentro de una lista, pero cuando pongo la variable dentro de index() me marca un error. Cómo puedo pasar ese valor usando la variable?.
Gracias :D

Comment: Al hacer `pop()` sacaste el elemento de la lista; ya no está más dentro de ella, por lo que `index` no lo encuentra. Es asi como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vemos la documentación del método [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), lo importante que hace a tu pregunta es:

> Quita el ítem en la posición dada de la lista y lo retorna.

Por lo que, al menos en este ejemplo, al no haber otro elemento cuyo valor sea 9,  `index()` termina generando un excepción `ValueError` (tal como figura en la misma documentación enlazada) por que ya la lista no tiene ese elemento.

Puedes eventualmente obtener el último valor sin quitarlo de la lista:

```
lista=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ultimo=lista[-1]
print(lista.index(ultimo))
```

`lista[-1]` es la forma de recortar la lista al último elemento sin modificar esta.

Comment: Mil Gracias. Creo que entendí mal lo de pop, pensé que solo se asignaba el valor a mi variable último, no que lo "extraía" totalmente de la lista. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el ultimo valor de la lista sin que me lo borre?

Comment: Esta en la respuesta, con `lista[-1]` haces un slice o recorte de la lista al último elemento

Comment: cierto, no lo noté. No pensé que fuera tan sencillo como eso. Muchas gracias!